# How to retrieve Table value from database in thymeleaf , hibernate using nested attribute?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, thymeleaf

I am creating a simple Spring boot web appliction using Thymeleaf and hibernate. So planning to display product category from product entity, where each category belongs to many product and one product has only one category.

wish to display all product, but some how i am not able to display product category using nested attribute .

> [[${product.category.name}]]

it gives below error

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Jan 31 03:46:01 CET 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/products.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/products.html]")
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1393)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1077)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    
    private Integer id;
    @Column(length=128, nullable=false,unique=true)
    private String name;
    private float price;
    
    
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    public Category category ;


    
    public Product() {}

    public Product(Integer id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }



    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }



    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }



    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }



    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }



    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

}
```

[image: enty relationship diagram]

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository ProductRepo;
    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepo;
    
    @GetMapping("products/new")

    public String showProductForm(Model model) {
        
    List<Category> listCategories=categoryRepo.findAll();   
    model.addAttribute("product", new Product());   
    model.addAttribute("listCategories", listCategories);   

    return "product_form";      
        
    }

    
    @PostMapping("/products/save")
    public String saveProduct(Product product) {
        
        ProductRepo.save(product);
        return "redirect:/";
        
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/products")
    public String listProducts(Model model) {
        
        List <Product> listProducts=ProductRepo.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("listProducts",listProducts);
        
        return "products";
    }
    
    
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>List Categories </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-center">
<div><h1> Products List</h1></div>

<div>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        
        </thead>
    
        <tbody>
          <th:block th:each="product : ${listProducts}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>[[${product.id}]]</td>
                            <td>[[${product.name}]]</td>
                            <td>[[${product.price}]]</td>
                        <td>[[${product.category.name}]]</td>
                        //error in displaying product category name 
                
              
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the error was here:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
public Category category ;
```

You can try this on Product Entity:

```
@ManyToOne(optional=true)
private Category category;
```

And on Category Entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
private List<Product> product;
```